# I think do while is getting into infinite loop. or the array. (run time error)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, do-while

it's a basic program for array of pointer to objects.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class city
{
protected:
    char *name;
    int len;
public:
    city()
    {
        len=0;
        name= new char[len+1];
    }
    void getname(void)
    {
        char *s;
        s= new char[30];
        cout<< "enter city name";
        cin >> s;
        len= strlen(s);
        name = new char[len+1];
        strcpy(name, s);
    }
    void printname(void)
    {
        cout<< name <<"\n";
    }
};
```

compiler says problem is in the "cout<< name <<"\n";"

```
int main()
{
    city *cptr[10];

    int n=1;
    int option;

    do
    {
        cptr[n]= new city;
        cptr[n]->getname();
        n++;
        cout<< "continue? yes=1, no=0. select now?";
        cin>> option;
    }
    while(option);

    cout<< endl<< endl;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cptr[i]-> printname();
    }

    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
    return 0;
};
```

There's also a warning(this warning is not an issue)

```
warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
```

I tried `strcpy_s` to remove the warning, but the word is unrecognized.

Comment: Couldn't you use C++ strings instead of array of characters? In getname() you should delete the old array 'name' before creating a new one. Also, you should delete s before you leave the block (or just use static arrays).

Comment: i am practicing on array of characters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cptr` is an array of character pointers. And the size of the array is fixed to 10:

```
city *cptr[10];
```

This makes `0` to `9` as the valid index into the array. But your do-while loop does not perform this check. If the user keeps continuing by inputting `1` you'll go and write beyond the array.

And array index in C++ start with `0` and not `1` so

```
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

should be:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
```

And

```
int n=1;
```

should be

```
int n=0;
```

Also consider using `strncpy` in place of `strcpy.`

Also you are leaking memory by not freeing the memory allocated to `s`. You need to free it by calling `delete`:

```
char *s;
s= new char[30];
// use it
delete[]s;
```

Comment: @stefanB: There is no `=<` operator in C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter more than `9` (I believe) entries, meaning you keep going past, you overwrite memory because you keep incrementing index in loop and you are not checking if you reached end of array, so you will go over.

Answer (score 1):

You really hate memory in this example :) Once you have allocated memory you MUST free it.

1. You need to declare destructor where you will free memory pointed by `city::name`;
2. In `city::getname()`, you need to free memory twice:

   - before you reassign `name` pointer;
   - before the method returns;
3. And finally you need to free memory allocated for `cptr` before returning from `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `i<=n` with `i<n` in ...

```
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

Comment: @jeet.mg: This does avoid the run time error but ignores the real problem of not understanding 0-based array indexes.

Comment: @jeet.mg: Read codaddict's answer. The valid indexes for a 10 element array are 0..9.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Granted starting index at 0 is better, but not necessary. Starting at 1 is confusing, however, the REAL problem is that there is no upper bound check on the array. If you index from 1 and try to cram more than 9 elements into the array (or if you start at 0 and cram more than 10 elements into the array) -- which is possible in the code -- then it blows up with a run-time error.